# Is there a simple / elegant way to push a Range of integers to an STD vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have a simple task which is to initialize an `std::vector<int>` with a range of integers.

The range is given by the user, and i try to avoid using a `for` loop.

Something like:

```
void addRange(std::vector<int>& vReturn, int nStart, int nEnd)
{
    vReturn.clear();

    // straightforward solution
    for (int nInteger = nStart; nInteger <= nEnd; nInteger++)
    {
         vReturn.push_back(nInteger);
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Elegent Pseudo-Code
    vReturn.add_range(nStart, nEnd);   // <<- is this doable?

}
```

Comment: since you use C++11, why not `std::vector<int> addRange(int nStart, int nEnd)` as signature and return the vector by-value? Furthermore, why the `const` for your function parameters?

Comment: @TemplateRex - the `const` are redundant, just a habbit of mine to define any `[in]` parameter as `const` although passed by value... this makes the interface much more clear with what is `[in]` and what is `[out]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in C++11, using algorithm [iota](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

```
vReturn.clear();
vReturn.resize((nEnd - nStart) + 1);
std::iota(vReturn.begin(), vReturn.end(), nStart);
```

You can also use [boost::irange](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html).

```
auto range = boost::irange<int>(nStart, nEnd + 1);
vReturn.assign(range.begin(), range.end());
```

Comment: what about using std::copy?

Comment: @WileTheCoyot where? Why not use assign?

Comment: what are the differences betwen std::copy and std::iota?

Comment: @WileTheCoyot please look at link, that is in post. copy just copy. iota fill the range with incremented values.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution and it does not use for loop and does not use boost or C++11

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Add{

  void operator()(int x, int y, vector<int>& vec)
  {
    if(x > y)
      return;

    vec.push_back(x);
    operator()(++x, y, vec);
  }
};

void addRange(std::vector<int>& vReturn, const int nStart, const int nEnd)
{
   vReturn.resize(nEnd - nStart); 
   vReturn.clear(); 
   Add()(nStart, nEnd, vReturn);  //update the vector using Functor object
}

int main()
{
   vector<int> vec;
   int start = 1, end = 10;

   addRange(vec, start , end);


   return 0;
}
```